# Prevent Membership Tables From Being Created

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am in the process of converting an old WebForms app that used membership to using Identity.

I have the Identity tables in my SQL server database and I can do the necessary CRUD operations on them.

But, then, once I start my app and I login with one of my users, all of the Membership tables ('UsersInRoles', 'Roles', 'Profiles', 'Memberships', 'Users', and 'Applications') are recreated.

I need to know how to keep those tables from being created (because of our policies), so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for any help,

Bob

---

So, I think that have found what is causing it, but I still have no idea what to do about it.
In my web.config, I have the following section:

```
<profile defaultProvider="ProfileProviderSql" automaticSaveEnabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ProfileProviderSql" connectionStringName="AppServices" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" applicationName="GMSApp" />
    </providers>
    <properties>
        <add name="CurrentAppId" type="string" defaultValue="" />
        <add name="ProjectNumber" type="string" defaultValue="" />
        <add name="ProjectAdjustmentNumber" type="int" defaultValue="0" />
        <add name="Theme" type="string" defaultValue="Pachanga" />
        <add name="UserAgencyID" type="int" defaultValue="0" />
        <add name="UserFirstName" type="string" defaultValue="" />
        <add name="UserLastName" type="string" defaultValue="" />
        <add name="UserContactPhone" type="string" defaultValue="" />
        <add name="ProjectHeader" type="string" defaultValue="" />
        <add name="IsBaselined" type="bool" defaultValue="false" />
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And the tables are being created when a line of code calls:

```
if (!PageBase.IsBaselined)
```

My PageBase code for IsBaselined is:

```
public static bool IsBaselined
{
    get { return ((bool)(HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("IsBaselined"))); }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Profile.SetPropertyValue("IsBaselined", value); }
}
```

So, I assume that the "profile defaultProvider="ProfileProviderSql" is what is causing the tables to be created, but I'm not sure what I should use to keep the functionality but not keep the table creation.

I hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I'm sorry that you infer that someone who has a problem is a "new" coder even though they have been coding since the late 70's.
And apparently, searching Google, Bing and StackOverflow for a week with absolutely no results is not doing enough research.
I set breakpoints in my code, stepped through and the tables are created between one line of code and the next.
That doesn’t give me any clues and so I still need some help and not criticism.

Comment: So likely that line of code causes it to be created. You need to provide more information in the question, such as showing the line of code that is relevant, explaining what role managers you have configured etc. Likely this will involve some research on your part, we can't do that for you.

Comment: I wasn't inferring anything Bob and I'm sorry if you took it that way. Without seeing any of the code in question the only thing anyone could do to help you would be a very wild guess. That's why my comment included a reference to what is known around here as a MCV (Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Dave - Sorry that I took it the wrong way. I guess the frustration of dealing with this is getting to me. This is the very last thing I need to take care of in my project and I have been trying to figure it out off and on for months - its driving me crazy.

Comment: The code you have posted seems like unrelated and not related to the problem asked.